# How to get the week number and rename a batch file

Tags: batch-file

Need to rename a file with the previous week number using batch script as below

[[image: sample]]

Tried the following code but it didn't give any output

```
call getTimeStamp /f {isowk} /r week
echo ISO 8601 week = %week%
```

Comment: 'gettimestamp' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.

Comment: @Magoo Is there another way to obtain the week?

Comment: Where & what is `gettimestamp`? If it is a batch file, please `edit` in the file to your question. Where does the response you posted appear, or is it an existing filename?

Comment: I took it from another code, its not a file name

Comment: You cannot just take a command from other code and not include the files used. If you do not have `getTimeStamp` which is clearly a batch-file, then the command does not exist. I can recreate such a file. However, you seem to be refering to Dbenham's [`getTimeStamp.bat`](https://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=7523)

Comment: Is there any method to take the week number??

Comment: Yes there is. `for /F "tokens=3*delims=_" %%i in ("Weekly_Data_17.csv") do echo %%~ni` but that is only going to work if you have this exact file format.

Comment: What happens if the week number is `1` or `01`? Are you going to just assume that the replacement is `52`?

Comment: ...AND you should take particular care if you want to derive the previous week number. Logically, it's that value -1, but this has to be specially treated if the week number has a leading `0`. You should also consider what happens with week `1` or `01`.

Comment: yes, i refered https://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=7523 this but still I'm unable to get an output as I mentioned in the image

Comment: This code helped me to get the current week ,  should adjust to get the previous week though (@for /f %%a in ('powershell.exe get-date -UFormat %%V') do @set WeekInYear=%%a)

Comment: Getting the current week however is not your intention, is it? The script would need to isolate the digit(s) following the underscore at the end of the file basename; then you'd need to store and use that to get the resulting date, in the 'assumed' current year, associated with that week in year figure; then you'd need to determine the week in year for that date minus one week, and return that for your intended renamed file basename. As it stands, there are far too many things you've not yet worked out how to do, and as such your question is far too broad at present, and therefore off topic.